# Are Polish PhD compatible with Germany and UK?

Tags: phd

I have two questions in this regard:

1. If someone completes a PhD in Poland, would it be considered on par with a German or British PhD?
2. Can a Polish-PhD holder enter academia in Germany or UK?

Comment: Since Poland is in the EU, the answer is [yes for Germany](https://www.kmk.org/fileadmin/Dateien/pdf/ZAB/Gradfuehrung_Beschluesse_der_KMK/20150626_KMK-Beschluss_Beguenstigende_Regelungen.pdf) and I assume it's the same for the UK. I've had a Polish colleague and she had no issues at all.

Comment: I would be surprise if not. It can take some time to prepare an equivalent diploma.

Comment: 1. Yes. 2. Yes.

Comment: The only profession where I'm aware that some burocracy will probably lurk is medicine/health practicioners. But not about PhD level research capabilities but to get the license transfered (EU means the process is now much easier and clearer than it used before).

Comment: @Roland As far as I know, the UK has no plams to exit the Bologna Process even if it withdrawals from the EU, so EU membership shouldn't matter here.

Comment: @cbeleites Well, does a PhD qualify someone to practice medicine anyway? I thought a MBBS or equivalent degree is required.

Comment: @xuq01: no, and that was my point: in order to practice medicine one needs the so-called Approbation in Germany, which is a kind of license that is different from the degree: the degree is necessary but not sufficient. A Polish MD (or however they call it) should be sufficient for lab-only research, though (for which, OTOH, a biochemistry/biology/... degree may actually be better). I know some "foreign MDs" (from and in different countries) who went into 100% research because of too much hassle to get a license in their new country.

Comment: @cbeleites Yes, that makes sense. It seems that a PhD usually doesn't prepare one for the training necessary for practicing medicine anyways.

Answer (score 1):

All the mentioned countries are members of the Bologna process: http://www.ehea.info/pid34250/members.html

Bologna process unifies the structure of higher education to levels of bachelor, master and doctoral degrees; see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bologna_Process. As far as I know, doctoral degrees from the various countries are generally accepted in the others, but I could not find a clear statement to the effect.

Answer (score 1):

There are two answers two this question.

The first is the legal answer. In general, if your PhD is a "proper" doctorate, that is involving the usual years of research and a properly defended thesis, it will be considered equivalent. In your case this is done by the Bologna accord which Poland, Germany and the UK signed and in which doctoral degrees are the "third cycle". (As a side note, there are some degrees such as the Czech PhDr which have the word doctor in their name but are given after what effectively is a master's thesis. They generally don't count, as a certain German politician had to find out some years ago.)

The second is the practical answer. Will the people who have to hire you consider you to be good enough? This one you'll mostly have to answer for yourself. In academia, at the level of post-doc and above, people generally aren't hired because they have a certain degree but because of their work, which usually means interesting research and publications. In general, if you are good enough, you can enter academia anywhere (at worst with increased bureaucracy) and if you aren't, your degree won't help you, no matter in which country you got it.

As a personal side note, the polish math PhD students I talked with, I would definitely consider equivalent to their German counterparts. But if you apply to Germany I hope you know some German, since many positions here involve some teaching.

Comment: "...  the polish math PhD students I talked with ..." --- what about other STEM?

Comment: I also know very good Polish groups in my field (analytical chemistry/data analysis) - their PhDs work as postdoc quite across Europe.